# How to generate colors for charts using js?

Tags: javascript, charts, colors

I want to generate colors for charts which is not repeated for certain numbers.
And also I don't want it to have similar colors for neighbors.
Is there any certain way to do something like this?

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

### [RGB and HEX](https://rcpmarketing.com/color-matching-system-pms-cmyk-rgb-hex/)

RGB is a color gamut of light using red, green, and blue to render colors onscreen. When designing for web, digital, or TV the RGB color system is used. HEX, which stands for Hexadecimal, is also used onscreen and is basically a short code for RGB color. A HEX color is a six-digit combination of letters and numbers. The first two numbers represent red, the middle two represent green, and the last two represent blue. In most programs the HEX number is automatically generated for you.

### The process

You can easily take either of those two formats and simply increase each individual part.
e.g `RGB: 0,0,0` will be black if we increase it to `(10,10,10)` the color result will be lighten black

if we however increase only the R part of it as such `(255,0,0)` your result will be red which in hex resolves to: `#FF0000` or `#F00` for short